# Are MacBook Pro display manufactured by Acer

Tags: macbook

This may be a strange question, but a friend of mine (an acer fan) assured me that Apple uses Acer to for their display.  I have not been able to confirm (or deny) this assertion?  Does somebody here know one way or the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never heard of Acer making LCDs AT ALL.  In fact, I don't know of them making much of anything themselves.  I think my Acer CD drive was made by Philips or Pioneer, and it sucked, so I never bought Acer after that.

Regardless, the main LCD manufacturers, in order, are Samsung, LG, Philips, Sharp, and Sony.  I think Dell might make their own too.  As far as I know, Apple just shop around for the best price/quality deal they can get on a product-by-product basis.

http://www.engadgethd.com/2006/07/27/overview-of-the-top-5-lcd-makers-2q-results/
http://svconline.com/flatscreens/features/lcd_market_watch_1108/

Comment: Dell uses LG panels, among others.  They probably use whatever is cheapest as well.

Answer (score 5):

Not all of them, certainly.  My MacBook Pro panel is a B154PW04 V6, manufactured by AU Optronics.  You can determine the panel by executing the following in a terminal window:

```
ioreg -lw0 | grep IODisplayEDID | sed "/[^<]*</s///" | xxd -p -r | strings -6
```

and then google the result.

I have not seen any manufactured by Acer, but it's certainly not impossible.

Comment: Mine is Samsung (using your genius oneliner)

Comment: How the hell did you work that out by the way?

Comment: I stole it from someone on the Internets.  :)  Wish I could claim credit for it.

Answer (score 1):

Just checked my 15" unibody and it's an LG panel...  I've never heard of Acer making panels for Apple either.

I know LG makes the panel in the Cinema Displays as well.  Again, perhaps not all of them.